# Moving a gameObject closer/farther to the HoloLens camera when the hand drags closer/farther to the HoloLens camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am currently stuck on a problem where I want to move a gameObject closer/farther to me (the HoloLens camera) when my hand forward/backward. Well, I have correctly implemented the logic to move the object closer/farther but couldn't work my way through determining the movement of the hand. 
I am using HoloToolkit's IManipulationHandler interface to move the object and this is the main logic that I am using right now:

```
void IManipulationHandler.OnManipulationUpdated(ManipulationEventData eventData)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectPosition, cameraPosition,
        - (eventData.CumulativeDelta * ManipulationSpeed).z);
}
```

(It only works fine when I don't change my position)

This is another logic I used:

```
void IManipulationHandler.OnManipulationUpdated(ManipulationEventData eventData)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectPosition, cameraPosition,
        Vector3.Distance(cameraPosition, eventData.CumulativeDelta));
}
```

According to above logic whenever I move my hand (forward or backward) the object always comes closer, because the distance b/w the two vectors always increases at first.

Kindly help me with this issue. Thankyou.

Note: I want to rotate the object when my hand drags left/right and to move the object closer/farther when my hand drags forward/backward.

Answer (score 1):

You may check out HandDraggable script from MixedRealityToolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are still using the HoloToolkit (now on the htk_development brunch), you can actually use the [TwoHandManipulatable](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/htk_development/Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/Scripts/Utilities/Interactions/TwoHandManipulatable.cs) to achieve that. Otherwise, you may have to write your own solver. I don't recommend people to implement that from scratch, it is painful.

With `TwoHandManipulatable.cs`, you can move the object towards any direction. If you want to limit the direction (e.g. only towards the cam), you can override that in your own class.

In my application, I use voice command as a second choice to the hand gestures by modifying SimpleTagAlong scripts. Then associate this action with speech keywords "closer/further". In my experience with end users, they will thank you for having the voice command.

Comment: Yeah, I also used voice command in my app. But my supervisor rejected that idea. Then I used buttons, that also got rejected. He wanted both the things with a single gesture.
Well, he got what he wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou... But my problem got solved when I used INavigationHandler interface instead of IManipulationHandler. I worked like a charm. Thanks again.